# Trying to understand the Flush argument behavior in print python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python print flush:

```
from time import sleep 
print("Hello, world!", end='')
sleep(5)
print("Bye!!!")
```

Ideally, in this scenario, Hello world! and Bye!! should be printed together as flush is defaulted to False. But when I am running this, it is print Hello world! and then after 5 seconds, printing Bye!!.

and I have tried the flush=False and flush=True one by one. But these also behaving exactly same

can any one please help me in finding a way to observe the behavior of flush, practically?

Comment: What other programming language do you know which uses flush?

Comment: What's the environment in which this code is running?  The concept of flushing output is defined in terms of a textual console, if your output is being display by something like a GUI widget in an IDE there's no reason to expect it to behave the same.

Comment: @jasonharper actually I am in learning phase and your comment make much sense.. I am using jupyter notebook and spyder to run the same.. should I try something else to see that behavior?

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper i just got it what you are trying to say. I ran it via cmd terminal and it worked.